# SQL look up a date and match to another column with multiple dates

Tags: mysql

Here is my issue: I have Table A with multiple date with multiple Y/N response

Table A:
[image: 1/1/2020 N 5/1/2020 Y 6/1/2020 N 12/1/2020 Y 4/1/2021 Y 9/1/2021 N 3/1/2022 Y]

In Table B I have a value of : 9/15/2020

I want to return the Y/N value of the month 6/1/2020 as 'N" because 9/15/2020 is between 6/1/2020 and 12/1/2020 and I would want the Y/N value of the earlier date.

I have tried using BETWEEN and creating MIN and MAX columns but the problem is there are multiple MIN and MAXes of both Y and N.

Answer (score 1):

Refer query below -

```
select * from tableA 
  where date_1 = (
     select max(date_1) from tableA 
       where date_1 < 
         (select date_1 from tableB) -- Assuming only one value in tableB
  );
```

DB fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=27794adcbf4889bf5e4e713e19ac5b15).

Comment: I think this will work. I have to re-write my whole code because Table B was actually the main table I wrote everything from. But  I think this is working now :)